# Error in retrieving financial data for large list of tickers from yahoo finance into a dataframe using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, yahoo-finance

In this particular problem, I have a very long list of tickers for which I want to retrieve some of the financial information from yahoo finance website using python:

here is the list:

```
tickers = ["OMKAR.BO", "KCLINFRA.BO", "MERMETL.BO", "PRIMIND.BO", "VISIONCO.BO", "PANAFIC.BO", "KARANWO.BO", "SOURCEIND.BO", "WELCURE.BO", "NAVKETAN.BO", "CUBIFIN.BO", "IMPEXFERRO.BO", "MISHTANN.BO", "SUMERUIND.BO", "MISHTANN.BO", "MADHUVEER.BO", "TNTELE.BO", "JMGCORP.BO", "GSLSEC.BO", "DEVKI.BO", "MINAXI.BO", "INNOCORP.BO", "SURYACHAKRA.BO", "ANKITMETAL.BO", "HAVISHA.BO", "SHIVA.BO", "COMFINTE.BO", "KONNDOR.BO", "PAZEL.BO", "SHARPINV.BO", "MIDINFRA.BO", "UNIVPRIM.BO", "ATHARVENT.BO", "FGP.BO", "BKV.BO", "VIVIDHA.BO", "FISCHER.BO", "ADITRI.BO", "GLFL.BO", "RAJOIL.BO", "ALFL.BO", "PURITY.BO", "ARCEEIN.BO", "INTECH.BO", "MIDEASTP.BO", "STANCAP.BO", "OCTAVE.BO", "TRIJAL.BO", "SREEJAYA.BO", "4THGEN.BO", "RICHIRICH.BO", "VIRTUALS.BO", "SAVINFOCO.BO", "TTIENT.BO", "OONE.BO", "TILAK.BO", "XTGLOBAL.BO", "MANGIND.BO", "ROYALIND.BO", "ASHUTPM.BO", "SMPL.BO", "BGPL.BO", "NYSSACORP.BO", "BILENERGY.BO", "YOGISUNG.BO", "DOLPHMED.BO", "PRATIK.BO", "IPOWER.BO", "BIHSPONG.BO", "CAPFIN.BO", "MCLTD.BO", "KGL.BO", "OMNIAX.BO", "HEERAISP.BO", "VISIONCINE.BO", "SWORDEDGE.BO", "AARVINFRA.BO", "ADVENT.BO", "UVDRHOR.BO", "SUNGOLD.BO", "USHDI.BO", "HINDAPL.BO", "IMEC.BO", "ARAVALIS.BO", "SERVOTEACH.BO", "SCAGRO.BO", "UMESLTD.BO", "CHARMS.BO", "NCLRESE.BO", "SYMBIOX.BO", "PRADIP.BO", "INTEGFD.BO", "CLIOINFO.BO", "RRSECUR.BO", "MUKATPIP.BO", "SYNCOMF.BO", "DYNAMICP.BO", "TRABI.BO", "RADAAN.BO", "KIRANSY-B.BO", "RAMSARUP.BO", "UNIMOVR.BO", "MELSTAR.BO", "OMANSH.BO", "VERTEX.BO", "VENTURA.BO", "GEMSPIN.BO", "EXPLICITFIN.BO", "PASARI.BO", "BABA.BO", "MAHAVIRIND.BO", "BAMPSL.BO", "GAJRA.BO", "SUNRAJDI.BO", "ACCEL.BO", "SIMPLXPAP.BO", "PHARMAID.BO", "JATALIA.BO", "TWINSTAR.BO", "CINDRELL.BO", "SHRGLTR.BO", "EUROMULTI.BO", "CRESSAN.BO", "SEVENHILL.BO", "QUADRANT.BO", "PHTRADING.BO", "SIPTL.BO", "HOTELRUGBY.BO", "KAUSHALYA.BO", "YASHRAJC.BO", "ASHAI.BO", "BERYLSE.BO", "LLOYDSTEEL.BO", "SCANPRO.BO", "HBLEAS.BO", "ASHCAP.BO", "SUNSHINE.BO", "AREALTY.BO", "MSCTC.BO", "HARIAEXPO.BO", "CNIRESLTD.BO", "KABRADG.BO", "CLFL.BO", "TRANSASIA.BO", "KACL.BO", "JAIHINDS.BO", "SANBLUE.BO", "DHENUBUILD.BO", "DHENUBUILD.BO", "ODYCORP.BO", "SAWABUSI.BO", "KAKTEX.BO", "GANONPRO.BO", "GENUSPRIME.BO", "EUREKAI.BO", "CHROMATIC.BO", "ISHWATR.BO", "INTEGRA.BO", "KACL.BO", "SSLFINANCE.BO", "ORIENTTR.BO", "ZHINUDYP.BO", "SWADEIN.BO", "SHKALYN.BO", "BAPACK.BO", "MARUTISE.BO", "PMTELELIN.BO", "SPARCSYS.BO", "GOLKONDA.BO", "DECPO.BO", "NATHUEC.BO", "INDOCITY.BO", "IOSYSTEM.BO", "ADVIKCA.BO", "JRFOODS.BO", "INFOMEDIA.BO", "INDRANIB.BO", "REGTRUS.BO", "RAGHUNAT.BO", "DCMFINSERV.BO", "RRIL.BO", "FILATFASH.BO", "ISWL.BO", "ASINPET.BO", "KORE.BO", "UNIOFFICE.BO", "GUJINV.BO", "QUEST.BO", "GLITTEKG.BO", "AMFORG.BO", "LGBFORGE.BO", "MAL.BO", "CYBERMAT.BO", "AGRIMONY.BO", "METKORE.BO", "SKYLMILAR.BO", "KIRANPR.BO", "RAJSPTR.BO", "SHVFL.BO", "MPFSL.BO", "AMITINT.BO", "KREONFIN.BO", "GRAVITY.BO", "KACHCHH.BO", "STELLANT.BO", "DEVINE.BO", "ICSL.BO", "STELLAR.BO", "CORAGRO.BO", "ARCFIN.BO", "GAMMNINFRA.BO", "EMMSONS.BO", "OSCARGLO.BO", "HARIAAPL.BO", "CORNE.BO", "FACORALL.BO", "KANELIND.BO", "INDOASIAF.BO", "BHANDHOS.BO", "GAGANPO.BO", "SELMCL.BO", "VENLONENT.BO", "KBSINDIA.BO", "RAMAPETRO.BO", "UTIQUE.BO", "GUJSTATFIN.BO", "COUNCODOS.BO", "JDORGOCHEM.BO", "ANSHNCO.BO", "SILVERO.BO", "CONSTRONIC.BO", "SIPIND.BO", "ESARIND.BO", "GUJCOTEX.BO", "HILIKS.BO", "MINFY.BO", "LEENEE.BO", "DUGARHOU.BO", "JHACC.BO", "CINERAD.BO", "GCMCAPI.BO", "GCMCOMM.BO", "CHENFERRO.BO", "MANCREDIT.BO", "TRICOMFRU.BO", "VEGETABLE.BO", "JSHL.BO", "HATHWAYB.BO", "JAYIND.BO", "ROYALCU.BO", "DHANADACO.BO", "ELCIDIN.BO", "RAGHUTOB.BO", "GISOLUTION.BO", "RAGHUTOB.BO", "CONTICON.BO", "NETWORK.BO", "BANASFN.BO", "CRANESSOFT.BO", "RSCINT.BO", "JPTRLES.BO", "ALOKTEXT.BO", "PRAGBOS.BO", "WELTI.BO", "EKAMLEA.BO", "MASL.BO", "SAFFRON.BO", "SRDAPRT.BO", "FFPL.BO", "RITESHIN.BO", "BLOIN.BO", "YARNSYN.BO", "OISL.BO", "POLYTEX.BO", "SPSINT.BO", "GCMCOMM.BO", "FRONTCAP.BO", "SEZAL.BO", "CITYMAN.BO", "AJEL.BO", "ESCORTSFIN.BO", "ABHIINFRA.BO", "PRATIKSH.BO", "JCTLTD.BO", "GENESIS.BO", "HINDSECR.BO", "GKCONS.BO", "MODWOOL.BO", "ROHITFERRO.BO", "NMSRESRC.BO", "VARIMAN.BO", "WAGEND.BO", "INDLEASE.BO", "APOORVA.BO", "HITTCO.BO", "PREMPIPES.BO", "SRMENERGY.BO", "KEDIACN.BO", "TOYAMIND.BO", "EPSOMPRO.BO", "RICHUNV.BO", "CITYONLINE.BO", "ELANGO.BO", "AMITSEC.BO", "CTL.BO", "LPDC.BO", "CONTCHM.BO", "NTL.BO", "SYBLY.BO", "ELEFLOR.BO", "KMFBLDR.BO", "TRIVIKRAMA.BO", "RUCHINFRA.BO", "PROMACT.BO", "USHAKIRA.BO", "ARUNAHTEL.BO", "CIL.BO", "MOUNTSHIQ.BO", "SPTRSHI.BO", "SEATV.BO", "SWASTIVI.BO", "SUNDARAM.BO", "CREATIVEYE.BO", "EUROASIA.BO", "ANJANIFIN.BO", "ADARSH.BO", "GLOBALCA.BO", "INDERGR.BO", "USGTECH.BO", "RASIELEC.BO", "SHEETAL.BO", "SYLPH.BO", "GOYALASS.BO", "KANSAFB.BO", "ANERI.BO", "DRL.BO", "OSWALOR.BO", "SWAGRUHA.BO", "SARTHAKIND.BO", "GALADA.BO", "OSWAYRN.BO", "TRINITYLEA.BO", "GOLCA.BO", "SODFC.BO", "LEADFIN.BO", "KAYPOWR.BO", "PANELEC.BO", "TARAI.BO", "SANJIVIN.BO", "MKTCREAT.BO", "ECOBOAR.BO", "SUNRINV.BO", "MAYURFL.BO", "GARWAMAR.BO", "SURYAKR.BO", "BESTAGRO.BO", "INDCEMCAP.BO", "EASTSILK.BO", "MPAGI.BO", "HRMNYCP.BO", "RUBRAME.BO", "INCON.BO", "AMRAPLIN.BO", "RESPONSINF.BO", "BACPHAR.BO", "KRISHNACAP.BO", "SHBHAWPA.BO", "TOWASOK.BO", "PADMALAYAT.BO", "MHSGRMS.BO", "JMTAUTOLTD.BO", "WELCON.BO", "UNITEDTE.BO", "MNPLFIN.BO", "PARSHINV.BO", "UNISHIRE.BO", "RAJINFRA.BO", "MMLF.BO", "ALCHCORP.BO", "CHMBBRW.BO", "NOGMIND.BO", "SHRMFGC.BO", "SAMTEX.BO", "SUPERTEX.BO", "JAIHINDPRO.BO", "CENTEXT.BO", "BCG.BO", "GENNEX.BO", "EDUCOMP.BO", "SHIVAGR.BO", "ADINATH.BO", "MINID.BO", "SURANAT&P.BO", "GYANDEV.BO", "AVTIL.BO", "ZSWASTSA.BO", "JINDCAP.BO", "NBFOOT.BO", "SHESHAINDS.BO", "UTLINDS.BO", "MADHUSE.BO", "THAMBBI.BO", "KKPLASTICK.BO", "VAGHANI.BO", "SOLIDCO.BO", "HIMFIBP.BO", "KKFIN.BO", "CSL.BO", "GOPAIST.BO", "BALTE.BO", "ETIL.BO", "PAOS.BO", "RAINBOWDQ.BO", "JAGSONFI.BO", "REGENTRP.BO", "AFEL.BO", "BRIPORT.BO", "SURATEX.BO", "INFRAIND.BO", "SPENTEX.BO", "TITANSEC.BO", "ALPSINDUS.BO", "UNISTRMU.BO", "SPECMKT.BO", "SAENTER.BO", "TOKYOFIN.BO", "TRANSFD.BO", "BSELINFRA.BO", "WELSPLSOL.BO", "SONALAD.BO", "CRIMSON.BO", "UNITY.BO", "VIKASPROP.BO", "VELHO.BO", "SYNCOM.BO", "CYBELEIND.BO", "VANICOM.BO", "THAKRAL.BO", "INDOEURO.BO", "ALAN SCOTT.BO", "SALSTEEL.BO", "ADITYA.BO", "HASTIFIN.BO", "NIBE.BO", "JOINTECAED.BO", "GANGAPHARM.BO", "SBECSUG.BO", "EASTBUILD.BO", "LORDSHOTL.BO", "IYKOTHITE.BO", "URJAGLOBA.BO", "DHRUVCA.BO", "RAP.BO", "LAHL.BO", "MONNETIN.BO", "SETUINFRA.BO", "RRMETAL.BO", "GTLINFRA.BO", "ECOM.BO", "TTML.BO", "ARNOLD.BO", "FLORATX.BO", "GARODCH.BO", "PUROHITCON.BO", "KAMRLAB.BO", "MILESTONE.BO", "NETLINK.BO", "MARSONS.BO", "SESL.BO", "OBRSESY.BO", "VRWODAR.BO", "NUWAY.BO", "CJGEL.BO", "REDEXPR.BO", "AISHWARYA.BO", "PICTUREHS.BO", "BAGFILMS.BO", "WOODSVILA.BO", "MEHSECU.BO", "MBPARIKH.BO", "SICLTD.BO", "GITARENEW.BO", "DESHRAK.BO", "SENINFO.BO", "TELECANOR.BO", "STLSTRINF.BO", "JRELTD.BO", "OROSMITHS.BO", "MUNOTHFI.BO", "AVAILFC.BO", "NITINFIRE.BO", "PIFL.BO", "BLBLIMITED.BO", "SRECR.BO", "NAGTECH.BO", "ARISE.BO", "FRONTBUSS.BO", "PAEL.BO", "ROLLT.BO", "VALLABH.BO", "RANASUG.BO", "STRATMONT.BO", "SANTOSHF.BO", "SVAINDIA.BO", "PARKERAC.BO", "VSFPROJ.BO", "AUROCOK.BO", "HKG.BO", "CASTEXTECH.BO", "HOWARHO.BO", "RTNPOWER.BO", "SHRIBCL.BO", "GARWSYN.BO", "MEHSECU.BO", "PRAVEG.BO", "MEHTAHG.BO", "RTNINFRA.BO", "MMWL.BO", "GAGAN.BO", "WWALUM.BO", "HEMANG.BO", "DOLAT.BO", "SUPTANERY.BO", "EUROCERA.BO", "SURFI.BO", "TTIL.BO", "VARDHMAN.BO", "SUPERBAK.BO", "ESHAMEDIA.BO", "CONTILI.BO", "CESL.BO", "DAULAT.BO", "RAJATH.BO", "SURYVANSP.BO", "KUWERIN.BO", "SVARTCORP.BO", "SKRABUL.BO", "WSIND.BO", "DELTA.BO", "SIPL.BO", "RMCHEM.BO", "STDBAT.BO", "PICCASUG.BO", "AGIOPAPER.BO", "SHREYASI.BO", "CCCL.BO", "GAL.BO", "GOLECHA.BO", "RAAJMEDI.BO", "KINETRU.BO", "ZKHANDEN.BO", "LAKHOTIA.BO", "SANINFRA.BO", "KABSON.BO", "ENTRINT.BO", "SIROHIA.BO", "3IINFOTECH.BO", "MEHIF.BO", "BASANTGL.BO", "MAITRI.BO", "CEENIK.BO", "MAXIMAA.BO", "STANPACK.BO", "CRANEINFRA.BO", "CHITRTX.BO", "CAPRICORN.BO", "TAVERNIER.BO", "JPPOWER.BO", "PATIDAR.BO", "BANSTEA.BO", "NEWMKTADV.BO", "DANUBE.BO", "MAHALXSE.BO", "SARDAPPR.BO", "KZLFIN.BO", "ABHIFIN.BO", "AVI.BO", "GAYATRIBI.BO", "VXLINSTR.BO", "ADITYASP.BO", "OMKARPH.BO", "ESSARSEC.BO", "SALSAIN.BO", "NDASEC.BO", "PARABDRUGS.BO", "EPIC.BO", "HIGHSTREE.BO", "TRIMURTHI.BO", "DBSTOCKBRO.BO", "ADARSHPL.BO", "SONAL.BO", "FRASER.BO", "BRIDGESE.BO", "GBGLOBAL.BO", "UNRYLMA.BO", "ANNAINFRA.BO", "RTEXPO.BO", "FUNDVISER.BO", "LIBORD.BO", "HYPERSOFT.BO", "JTAPARIA.BO", "ANUBHAV.BO", "MEGFI.BO", "ACTIONFI.BO", "BCLENTERPR.BO", "RAMSONS.BO", "GUJARATPOLY.BO", "SBFL.BO", "CHDCHEM.BO", "MONEYBOXX.BO", "ALSL.BO", "DEVHARI.BO", "NARPROP.BO", "PIONAGR.BO", "JAYBHCR.BO", "QGO.BO", "KRIFILIND.BO", "GOLDCOINHF.BO", "GALLOPENT.BO", "MIC.BO", "INTELLCAP.BO", "ABIRAFN.BO", "OLPCL.BO", "ZSHERAPR.BO", "CELLA.BO", "ZSANMCOM.BO", "STEELCO.BO", "VFL.BO", "MODAIRY.BO", "ZSANMCOM.BO", "STEELCO.BO", "SHUKJEW.BO", "JAYKAY.BO", "MIC.BO", "MODAIRY.BO", "RGIL.BO", "GSBFIN.BO", "OLPCL.BO", "HINDMOTORS.BO", "GAJANANSEC.BO", "MKEXIM.BO", "BERLDRG.BO", "KUBERJI.BO", "ADDIND.BO", "INDOSOLAR.BO", "GOLDCOINHF.BO", "ACIIN.BO", "UNITINT.BO", "SDC.BO", "RAJKSYN.BO", "CHAMAK.BO", "BHILSPIN.BO", "PANORAMA.BO", "REGAL.BO", "KRRAIL.BO", "AMS.BO", "PARIKSHA.BO", "SURYAINDIA.BO", "ADHARSHILA.BO", "AMARNATH.BO", "JAYATMA.BO", "CANOPYFIN.BO", "FMEC.BO", "CITL.BO", "DAL.BO", "YORKEXP.BO", "MEWATZI.BO"]
```

and then what I am doing is as below in which I want to get Market Capitalization for each of the tickers in the above list:

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import pandas as pd

tickers = tick[0:30]
dat = data.get_quote_yahoo(tickers)['marketCap']
print(dat)
```

I am able to fetch 20-30 tickers using above code, but if I try to pull all, the code throws an error "request timed out" and "list out of range" etc.

Then I tried to fetch data one by one using for loop as below:

```
f = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Ticker", "MarketCapINR"])
columns = list(df)

for tick in ticks:
  dat = data.get_quote_yahoo(tick)['marketCap']
  zipped = zip(columns, dat)
  a_dictionary = dict(zipped)
  df = df.append(a_dictionary, ignore_index=True)
```

This returned me two errors, one of these is list out of bound and another (when I tried to shorten the length of list using 'slicing'), request timed out.

Is there a way out, to get all the data (ticker names in first column and MarketCap values in second column of a pandas dataframe) ??

..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using a package called [yahooquery](https://github.com/dpguthrie/yahooquery).  Disclaimer:  I am the author of the package.

```
from yahooquery import Ticker
import pandas as pd

tickers = [...] # Use your list above
t = Ticker(tickers)
data = t.quotes
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df['marketCap']
```

```
OMKAR.BO         4750000
KCLINFRA.BO     26331000
MERMETL.BO      11472136
PRIMIND.BO      22697430
VISIONCO.BO     14777874
                  ...
CANOPYFIN.BO    93859304
FMEC.BO         10542380
CITL.BO              NaN
YORKEXP.BO      57503880
MEWATZI.BO      51200000
Name: marketCap, Length: 632, dtype: object
```

Comment: never knew this one... but full credits to you for that work... awesome!!