# getting Market cap data using Yfinance

Tags: python, yfinance

I was trying to get market cap data of stocks using yfinance. Here is my code:

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web

tickers=pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/bse.xlsx')
UndervaluedCompanies=[]

market_cap_data = web.get_quote_yahoo(tickers)['marketCap']

# Get the P/E ratio directly
pe_data = web.get_quote_yahoo(tickers)['trailingPE']

# print stock and p/e ratio
for stock, pe in zip(tickers, pe_data):
print(stock, pe)
```

By using this code I get the following error:

*** IndexError: list index out of range

I attach screenshots of the error and also of the DataFrame

[image: Error]

[image: Tickers DataFrame]

I referred to the url as specified below as to circumvent this issue.

[Yfinance IndexError: list index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662791/yfinance-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range)

The modified code made using the fix given in the above url is:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import pandas_datareader as pdr

from pandas_datareader import data

data =pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/bse.xlsx')
ticker = data['Ticker']
rows = []

for ticker in ticker:

  try:
    market_data =  data.get_quote_yahoo(ticker)['marketCap']
  except IndexError as e:
    print(f'{ticker}: {e}')  # print the ticker and the error
    print('\n')
```

By using the above code I am getting an error as described in the screenshot:

By using the code I am getting the following error:

KeyError: 'regularMarketPrice

The screenshot of the same is as shown:

[image: Error]

On clicking on the file which is mentioned in error we can see that the error is caused by the function def_read_lines. The screenshot is attached below:

[image: Functions where error occours]

I did try using the yahooquery library but in the values dataframe all the values are populated as error values and not the actual market cap values as shown:

[image: values dataframe]

I am not understanding where am I going wrong. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Where are u using the `yfinance` library?

Comment: First I Import it:

import yfinance as yf

Then I use it here in ths line to calculate market cap:
market_data =  data.get_quote_yahoo(ticker)['marketCap']

Comment: BHARTIARTL.NS nan;ASHOKLEY.NS nan;AUROPHARMA.NS 15.902734;We were able to obtain market_cap_data for three issues, but the result is NaN because pe_data is NaN for two issues. The three stocks are ['BHARTIARTL.NS', 'ASHOKLEY.NS', and 'AUROPHARMA.NS'].

Comment: It works for some stocks but if you go for multiple stocks it gives error. I mean very large values. in this case I am trying to calculate the market cap for all the stocks registered in the BSE

Comment: Where are all the issues if there is a problem with some and not all? Are they available in text?

Comment: Have you seen this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64883529/error-in-retrieving-financial-data-for-large-list-of-tickers-from-yahoo-finance/64884161#64884161

Comment: I tried it. The code executes completely fine but in the dataframe all the values are shown as error instead of actual marketcap values

Comment: By introducing the library created by @putty , you were able to get 10 of your stocks with Puffy's answered code.

Comment: Convert your pandas series of tickers to a list:  data[‘Ticker’].tolist()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that some of the ticker in your excel file aren't listed or there is some kind of naming issue.
So i solved using try to download the stocks one by one with `data.get_quote_yahoo('ticker')` and then `with pd.concat()` I obtained my dataframe.

```
import yfinance as yf
from pandas_datareader import data
        
tickers=pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/bse.xlsx')
    
market_data=[]
  for ticker in tickers:
      print(ticker)
           try: 
               market_data.append(data.get_quote_yahoo(ticker)['marketCap'])
           except:
               print('Error with: ', ticker)
df=pd.concat(market_data, axis=0)
display(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample code that might resove your issue

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data

Tickers=["AAPL","GOOG","RY","HPQ"]

for str in Tickers:
    tickers = [(str)]
    print(tickers)

    market_cap=int(data.get_quote_yahoo(str)['marketCap'])
    print(market_cap)
```

Let me know if i misunderstood your question or any improvement that you might need

Comment: Hi your code works completely fine when adding small list. But when I try to download market cap for large values of tickers probably from an excel list it gives me an error on the     market_cap=int(data.get_quote_yahoo(str)['marketCap']) line saying that "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_quote_yahoo"

Comment: I have upgraded yfinance library

Comment: It did not fix my issue