# Market cap of all tickers in stock exchanges using python

Tags: python, stock, yfinance

I need to get the current market cap of all the tickers in the stock exchanges (NYSE and NASDAQ) along with their other information such as close, open, and etc (but these are optional).

Is there any way like a  csv file or api request that can give me this information?

I think yfinance api does not have this feature to return the market cap of all the tickers, right?

Comment: The market cap of the entire NYSE is 27.7 trilion dollars.  The market cap of all of NASDAQ is 23 trillion dollars.  Google is way faster than Python for this information.

Comment: I think [this question has already been answered on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64965121/getting-market-cap-data-using-yfinance). Just get a list of tickers and loop through. Or if you just want all of them combined, follow Tim's advice and use Google.

Comment: @TimRoberts I need the market cap of each ticker in these exchanges, not the total market cap of the exchanges.

Comment: @ramzeek, I think in that question, there is a file that has all the tickers and information, it doesn't say where the file comes from.

Comment: I'm pretty sure everything that you need to put together is a few Google searches away.

Comment: That's 5,700 stocks.  What are you going to do with this information?  It's not particularly useful.

Comment: Hi @MOH, and welcome to SO, it seem that you're asking a question without actually having tried or provided any code yourself, so please keep in mind that we don't just write code on demand, and that you need to do some effort on your own. See [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 3):

Use an API like [Financial Modeling Prep](https://site.financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs).

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

FMP_key = 'YOUR API KEY HERE'

# Define lists of symbols and market caps
symbols = []
market_caps = []

# Define a function to get the url based on your API key and 
def url(symbol: str, api_key):
    return "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/market-capitalization/" + symbol + "?apikey=" + api_key

# All the symbols you want the data for
all_symbols = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'NFLX', 'NVDA', 'FB', 'TWTR', 'TSLA', 'AMZN', 'WMT']

# DataFrame to store all the data
data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Symbol', 'Market Cap'])

# Iterate based on the symbols list and add to DataFrame
for item in all_symbols:
    response = requests.get(url(symbol = item, api_key = FMP_key)).json()

    symbols.append(response[0]['symbol'])
    market_caps.append(response[0]['marketCap'])
    
# Add data to the dataframe
data['Symbol'] = symbols
data['Market Cap'] = market_caps
```

The result:

[image: Result of code above.]

Comment: FYI: That is not a fully free service, the *free* only let you use 250 requests/day, for other [price](https://site.financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs/pricing/) options. The devpage (above) is misleading since it states that you can have: "*We have 1 minute, 15 minutes, 30 minutes, 1 hour and daily historical stock prices.*", which doesn't *seem* to be covered in the free list.

Comment: @not2qubit Definitely. I like Finnhub for my market data as when I'm not doing heavy market work, the free plan does the job better than I need.

Comment: Hm, yes, the free [Finnhub](https://finnhub.io/pricing) give you 60 API calls/minute, and limited to 50 symbols.

Comment: Finnhub [Python API](https://github.com/Finnhub-Stock-API/finnhub-python)

Answer (score 1):

Does the below code sample work for you? If not, I have a couple alternative sample scripts.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import DataFrame
import itertools
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="

tckr = ['MSFT','AAPL','AMZN']
        
i = 1

url_list = [(s, url_base + s) for s in tckr]
data_list = []

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}

for t, url in url_list:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
    print(t, url)
    print('Scrapping ticker {}...'.format(t))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    #writer.writerow([t])
    l = []
    for row in soup.select('.snapshot-table2 tr'):
        l.append([td.text for td in row.select('td')])
        x = list(chain.from_iterable(l))
        d = dict(zip(x[::2], x[1::2]))
        d['Index'] = t
        
    data_list.append(d)
```

-- Result:

```
Out[139]: 
[{'Index': 'MSFT',
  'P/E': '25.56',
  'EPS (ttm)': '9.59',
  'Insider Own': '0.07%',
  'Shs Outstand': '7.49B',
  'Perf Week': '-7.49%',
  'Market Cap': '1917.59B',
  'Forward P/E': '22.80',
  'EPS next Y': '15.54%',
  'Insider Trans': '-0.56%',
  'Shs Float': '7.46B',
  'Perf Month': '-8.19%',
  'Income': '72.46B',
  'PEG': '1.59',
  'EPS next Q': '2.31',
  'Inst Own': '71.80%',
  'Short Float': '0.62%',
  'Perf Quarter': '-17.02%',
  'Sales': '192.56B',
  'P/S': '9.96',
  'EPS this Y': '39.70%',
  'Inst Trans': '-0.62%',
  'Short Ratio': '1.43',
  'Perf Half Y': '-26.80%',
  'Book/sh': '21.74',
  'P/B': '11.27',
  'ROA': '21.40%',
  'Target Price': '360.65',
  'Perf Year': '-6.11%',
  'Cash/sh': '13.37',
  'P/C': '18.32',
  'EPS next 5Y': '16.11%',
  'ROE': '47.00%',
  '52W Range': '241.51 - 349.67',
  'Perf YTD': '-27.16%',
  'Dividend': '2.48',
  'P/FCF': '41.75',
  'EPS past 5Y': '25.70%',
  'ROI': '28.20%',
  '52W High': '-29.94%',
  'Beta': '0.94',
  'Dividend %': '1.01%',
  'Quick Ratio': '1.90',
  'Sales past 5Y': '13.00%',
  'Gross Margin': '68.70%',
  '52W Low': '1.43%',
  'ATR': '8.55',
  'Employees': '181000',
  'Current Ratio': '2.00',
  'Sales Q/Q': '18.40%',
  'Oper. Margin': '42.50%',
  'RSI (14)': '36.90',
  'Volatility': '2.69% 2.85%',
  'Optionable': 'Yes',
  'Debt/Eq': '0.40',
  'EPS Q/Q': '9.10%',
  'Profit Margin': '37.60%',
  'Rel Volume': '1.03',
  'Prev Close': '251.76',
  'Shortable': 'Yes',
  'LT Debt/Eq': '0.38',
  'Earnings': 'Apr 26 AMC',
  'Payout': '24.50%',
  'Avg Volume': '32.16M',
  'Price': '244.97',
  'Recom': '1.70',
  'SMA20': '-6.47%',
  'SMA50': '-10.19%',
  'SMA200': '-18.62%',
  'Volume': '33,061,518',
  'Change': '-2.70%'},
 {'Index': 'AAPL',
  'P/E': '21.14',
  'EPS (ttm)': '6.15',
  'Insider Own': '0.07%',
  'Shs Outstand': '16.28B',
  'Perf Week': '-8.82%',
  'Market Cap': '2189.63B',
  'Forward P/E': '19.84',
  'EPS next Y': '6.83%',
  'Insider Trans': '-1.58%',
  'Shs Float': '16.17B',
  'Perf Month': '-12.85%',
  'Income': '101.94B',
  'PEG': '2.13',
  'EPS next Q': '1.16',
  'Inst Own': '59.70%',
  'Short Float': '0.70%',
  'Perf Quarter': '-19.03%',
  'Sales': '386.02B',
  'P/S': '5.67',
  'EPS this Y': '71.40%',
  'Inst Trans': '-0.43%',
  'Short Ratio': '1.19',
  'Perf Half Y': '-27.46%',
  'Book/sh': '4.14',
  'P/B': '31.42',
  'ROA': '28.90%',
  'Target Price': '188.92',
  'Perf Year': '-1.31%',
  'Cash/sh': '3.06',
  'P/C': '42.51',
  'EPS next 5Y': '9.91%',
  'ROE': '152.90%',
  '52W Range': '128.46 - 182.94',
  'Perf YTD': '-26.76%',
  'Dividend': '0.92',
  'P/FCF': '24.05',
  'EPS past 5Y': '22.00%',
  'ROI': '50.00%',
  '52W High': '-28.91%',
  'Beta': '1.20',
  'Dividend %': '0.71%',
  'Quick Ratio': '0.90',
  'Sales past 5Y': '11.10%',
  'Gross Margin': '43.30%',
  '52W Low': '1.24%',
  'ATR': '5.23',
  'Employees': '154000',
  'Current Ratio': '0.90',
  'Sales Q/Q': '8.60%',
  'Oper. Margin': '30.90%',
  'RSI (14)': '33.79',
  'Volatility': '2.78% 3.31%',
  'Optionable': 'Yes',
  'Debt/Eq': '1.78',
  'EPS Q/Q': '9.20%',
  'Profit Margin': '26.40%',
  'Rel Volume': '1.13',
  'Prev Close': '135.43',
  'Shortable': 'Yes',
  'LT Debt/Eq': '1.53',
  'Earnings': 'Apr 28 AMC',
  'Payout': '14.20%',
  'Avg Volume': '95.49M',
  'Price': '130.06',
  'Recom': '1.90',
  'SMA20': '-8.73%',
  'SMA50': '-15.20%',
  'SMA200': '-18.27%',
  'Volume': '107,659,951',
  'Change': '-3.97%'},
 {'Index': 'AMZN',
  'P/E': '50.13',
  'EPS (ttm)': '2.07',
  'Insider Own': '9.80%',
  'Shs Outstand': '10.18B',
  'Perf Week': '-10.75%',
  'Market Cap': '1117.20B',
  'Forward P/E': '38.52',
  'EPS next Y': '238.07%',
  'Insider Trans': '-0.00%',
  'Shs Float': '457.72M',
  'Perf Month': '-10.15%',
  'Income': '21.41B',
  'PEG': '1.24',
  'EPS next Q': '0.16',
  'Inst Own': '60.70%',
  'Short Float': '21.70%',
  'Perf Quarter': '-34.07%',
  'Sales': '477.75B',
  'P/S': '2.34',
  'EPS this Y': '54.90%',
  'Inst Trans': '0.20%',
  'Short Ratio': '1.15',
  'Perf Half Y': '-40.19%',
  'Book/sh': '13.16',
  'P/B': '7.88',
  'ROA': '5.40%',
  'Target Price': '178.13',
  'Perf Year': '-40.58%',
  'Cash/sh': '6.16',
  'P/C': '16.83',
  'EPS next 5Y': '40.50%',
  'ROE': '16.90%',
  '52W Range': '101.26 - 188.65',
  'Perf YTD': '-37.82%',
  'Dividend': '-',
  'P/FCF': '-',
  'EPS past 5Y': '67.60%',
  'ROI': '9.50%',
  '52W High': '-45.05%',
  'Beta': '1.24',
  'Dividend %': '-',
  'Quick Ratio': '0.70',
  'Sales past 5Y': '28.10%',
  'Gross Margin': '42.10%',
  '52W Low': '2.37%',
  'ATR': '5.57',
  'Employees': '1622000',
  'Current Ratio': '1.00',
  'Sales Q/Q': '7.30%',
  'Oper. Margin': '4.10%',
  'RSI (14)': '37.30',
  'Volatility': '4.17% 4.11%',
  'Optionable': 'Yes',
  'Debt/Eq': '0.53',
  'EPS Q/Q': '-147.80%',
  'Profit Margin': '4.50%',
  'Rel Volume': '0.95',
  'Prev Close': '107.67',
  'Shortable': 'Yes',
  'LT Debt/Eq': '0.51',
  'Earnings': 'Apr 28 AMC',
  'Payout': '0.00%',
  'Avg Volume': '86.54M',
  'Price': '103.66',
  'Recom': '1.70',
  'SMA20': '-8.46%',
  'SMA50': '-18.17%',
  'SMA200': '-33.06%',
  'Volume': '81,975,496',
  'Change': '-3.72%'}]
```

Comment: For clarity, this is web scraping [Finnviz](https://finviz.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you overlook a bit in yfinance's provided info. There's actually the market capital of the stock, and of course, all other details. For example.

```
import yfinance as yf

msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
msft.info['marketCap']
Out[51]: 1999385657344
```

So, what you need here now is a list of all the stocks you can get from NYSE and NASDAQ. I do have a code written to collect all the stocks in Malaysia for research purposes, but I will provide it here and perhaps you can modify it to your own usage.

```
# Construction sectors' url
Construct_URL = "https://www.malaysiastock.biz/Listed-Companies.aspx?type=S&s1=3"

market_sectors = ['construction']
market_url = [Construct_URL]

import re
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

# The info of the companies in a sector from the sector url
def info(url, output_fname="sector.csv"):
    dfs = pd.read_html(url, match="ROE")
    out = dfs[1]
    out.to_csv(f"{output_fname}.csv")

# Obtain the company names into a dataframe
def sector_companies(input_fname="sector"):
    dfs = pd.read_csv(f"{input_fname}.csv", header=0)
    return dfs["Company"]

def sto_data(start, end, close_fname):  ## Retrieving data from all stocks
    company_names = []
    stocks_data = []
    for company_str in company_list:
        temp = re.search(r"\(\w+", company_str)
        res = company_str[temp.start() : temp.end()]
        company_name = str(res).strip()[1:]
        stock_code = f"{company_name}.KL"
        company_names.append(company_name)
        stock_data = yf.download(stock_code, start=start, end=end)
        df = pd.DataFrame(stock_data)
        stocks_data.append(df)

    result = pd.concat(stocks_data, axis=1)
    result_columns = ["Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Adj Close", "Volume"]
    headers = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([company_names, result_columns])
    result.to_csv(f"{close_fname}.csv", header=headers)


for i, j in zip(market_sectors, market_url):
    fname = i
    stocks_data_fname = f"{i}_stocks"
    start_date = "2021-01-01"
    end_date = "2021-12-31"
    url = j
    info(url, fname)
    company_list = sector_companies(fname)
    sto_data(start_date, end_date, stocks_data_fname)
```